# Is there a way to remove ID from link in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am working on ASP.NET MVC project. I am facing one problem now. I am redirecting from one action to other when I click on **Add list** option in my drop down.

This is the script I am using for redirection :

```
 $("#DrpList").change(function (e) {
     if ($(this).val() == 'Add List') {
         document.location.href = 'http://localhost:1234/report/Index/indexid'
```

Here **indexid** is just random id which I am passing and it is static, So I can compare this in my Index controller and display view I need.

Here what I want is, after i pass **indexid** parameter to index, when Index page displays, I can see indexid in my link like this,

```
http://localhost:1234/report/Index/indexid
```

but i just need to display,

```
http://localhost:1234/report/Index
```

I tried to do like :

```
return view("Index", "report", new{id = ""});
```

But it doesn't work. So how can I achieve this ?

**Update :**

```
 public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
  if (id == "indexid")
  {
  //Here Add items to list
 return View("Index", "report", new { id = "" });
  }
```

Comment: Is `indexid` is int or string?

Comment: @Murali it is a string

Comment: Check my answer, it might work for you

Comment: Yes. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31958586). You just need a data source to map the URL you want to use to the ID of the entity.

Answer (score 0):

Your Report Controller Index action signature should use `indexid` and not default `id`. Also indexid should be `nullable`

```
public class ReportController:Controller
{

   public ActionResult Index(string indexid)
   {

   }

}
```

and

```
 return view("Index", "report", new{indexid= ""});
```

Comment: Hi its not working. I already have string id which I am using in index. I think even if i change that to stringid, it doesnt make difference. I can see value indexid in id or stringid.But in return view, I am not able to make that null. I can see that in link

Comment: @Ajay, please add your action method code, especially signature in your post. It is hard to understand with out it

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActionFilter to route as per your requirement. Create an ActionFilter as shown below -

```
public class MyFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var rd = filterContext.RouteData;
        if(rd.Values.Keys.Contains("id"))
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Items["key"] = rd.Values["id"];
            rd.Values.Remove("id");
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Controller/Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Then use this Filter on the action where you are passing ID as the value -

```
    [MyFilter]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

You can access id value in the Action using `HttpContext.Items["id"]`.

When you request to a page with URL - `/Controller/Action/indexid`, it will be redirected to `/Controller/Index`