# How to customize route in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am working with website with MVC4.
Basic my web struct:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",             
                 defaults: new { controller = "ADMIN", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

But we have one page need to access with URL as: ABC.com/vairable.
How to config.
I config as below: but need to open with URL: ABC.com/Make/vairable:

```
        routes.MapRoute(


     "New",
        "Make/{PROMOTION_NAME}",
        new { controller = "Redeem", action = "MakeRedeem", PROMOTION_NAME = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
             null,
             new[] {"Project.Web.Controllers"});
```

Comment: Just in case: order matters, all your custom routes must be declared *before* the default route. Source: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need make a custom constraint to your role. And add your role before default role. Custom constraint prevents match all URLs user typed and filter irrelevant URL's so other roles could match them. Consider this:

```
public class MyCatConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    // suppose this is your promotions list. In the real world a DB provider 
    private string[] _myPromotions= new[] { "pro1", "pro2", "pro3" };

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, 
         string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
         // return true if you found a match on your pros' list otherwise false
         // In real world you could query from DB 
         // to match pros instead of searching from the array.  
         if(values.ContainsKey(parameterName))
         {
              return _myPromotions.Any(c => c == values[parameterName].ToString());
         }
         return false;
     }
}
```

now add a role before default role with `MyConstraint`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "promotions",
    url: "{PROMOTION_NAME}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Redeem", action = "MakeRedeem" },
    constraints: new { PROMOTION_NAME= new MyCatConstraint() },
    namespaces: new[] {"Project.Web.Controllers"}
);

// your other roles here
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",             
    defaults: new { controller = "ADMIN", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Now URL `example.com/pro1` maps to `Redeem.MakeRedeem` action method but `example.com/admin` maps to `Admin.Index`

Answer (score 1):

> We have one page need to access with URL as: ABC.com/vairable

There are basically 3 options, but I cannot give examples because you did not include any information as to what is expected to go in the "variable".

1. Use a [RegEx route constraint](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs).
2. Use a [custom route constraint](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs).
3. Create a custom `RouteBase` subclass. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31934144/multiple-levels-in-mvc-custom-routing/31958586#31958586).

Comment: I meet problem. for access that page, URL is ABC.com/Make/variable.
But I just want to URL: ABC.com/variable.
and in our control, the 'MakeRedeem' action will received that variable.
if user just input URL: ABC.com, the {PROMOTION_NAME} is null else is have value