# How to use URL parameter as a key in MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

In my MVC application , **RouteConfig** contains following code (by default):

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{key}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", key= UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

When a user hits my website (**abc.com**) or type **abc/Home/Index** , it invokes **Home/Index**. Problem is that I want to use key. I mean If a user enters **abc/someKey** or **abc/Home/Index/someKey** it should go to **Home/Index** where i can access that key. It works good in **abc/Home/Index/someKey** case but fails in **abc/someKey** & gives exception. Is there any other way to get that functionality ?

Comment: Because if you use `abc/someKey` it is trying to find a method name `Index` on `someKeyController`. You need to create specific routes

Comment: I know this. But I want to change the route file for the required stuff. I do have thousands of keys & certainly can not implement that many controllers. @StephenMuecke

Comment: The number of keys you have has nothing to do with it (you just pass the value as a parameter). But you will never be able to to use just `/abc/someKey` You need at least the controller name in the route

Comment: okay, how can I create specific routes in this case ? @StephenMuecke

Comment: It depends what you want to do but a route needs to be distinguishable. `abc/someKey` cannot work because its looking for `someKeyController`. You could do `abc/Home/someKey` to have you always go to the `Index` method of `HomeController`. But what is the issue with `abc/Home/Index/someKey` anyway?

Comment: Actually I want to implement subdomain concept. Every user can create its own domain on abc.com. I have another idea, I create a KeyController, if controller is not Home, then move to that KeyController > Index but don't know how to do it. :/ @StephenMuecke

Comment: You can make any URL scheme you want (including responding to subdomains) by using a [custom RouteBase subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31934144/multiple-levels-in-mvc-custom-routing/31958586#31958586). However, without more specifics of what you are trying to achieve, I can't give you a better example than that one.