# how to add multiple Url in MVC5 route.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

I am new to ASP.NET MVC5, I found one default route in routeconfig.cs file.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

so, If I am trying to access localhost:44300, I am redirecting to `Home/Index` action method.

So I am added Login page in `Home/Index` view page. after user successful login I am redirecting the user to `Home/Details` Method then In browser I am getting url as https://localhost:44300/Home/Details.

Here my question Is there any possibility to hide `Home/Details`  like `Home/Index`. I am tried with adding another default route but it is failed.

Comment: You can only have one _'default'_ route. What are you wanting to achieve. Why would you want to _'hide'_ the `Home/Details` route? (making it impossible for the user to navigate to it)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes. I don't want to show `Home/details` route  to user  (target is to display same url before and after login (https://localhost:44300) )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mask the controller and action name from the browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517047/how-to-mask-the-controller-and-action-name-from-the-browser)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding following route before your default route in RouteConfig.cs file -

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "Details",
url: "Home/Index/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This will convert - Home/Details to Home/Index

Comment: I have the same issue, after adding this I am getting Home/Index instead of Home/Details But there is no possibility to hide Home/Index

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to have the same url (`http://localhost:44300`) be mapped to 2 different controller actions. There can only be one default route.