# Async Route Constraint (or maybe something else) in .NET5/MVC6

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to create a route constraint, but this constraint needs to use one of my services, and this service method uses async.

Now ideally, the data that is returned from this routeConstraint, i would like to pass to the controller for use within the action that is being called, if the constraint has been met.

Users will call a controller with an extra parameter, we will call myName.  if this value appears in the database, i would like that record in the controller method.

Path to call controller looks like so, where data is the name of my controller, and myName is a string, that i need to check if it exists in the database.

http://localhost/api/data/myName

If myName doesnt exist, the controller should not be called.  If it does, then the method should be called, but with the myName value available.

Not sure if maybe i need to use something else then a route constraint?

**NOTE:
I cannot add this as a parameter against each method in this controller, so please do not suggest it.**

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own `IRouter`, which is resolved asynchronously by MVC6. `IRouter` is the interface that every route implements, so you are operating at a lower level.

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Routing
{
    public interface IRouter
    {
        // Populates route data (including route values) based on the
        // request
        Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context);

        // Derives a virtual path (URL) from a list of route values
        VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(VirtualPathContext context);
    }
}
```

`RouteAsync` does the following:

1. Analyzes the request to determine if it matches the route.
2. If we have a match, set the route values.
3. If we have a match, pass the call to the next `IRouter` (typically it is the `MvcRouteHandler`).

`GetVirtualPath` does the following:

1. Compares a set of route values to see if they match the route.
2. If it matches, converts the route values into a virtual path (URL). This should usually be the exact inverse of the logic in `RouteAsync` so we generate the same URL that is matched.
3. The framework returns the virtual path to any calls to the `UrlHelper`, such as those made by `ActionLink` and `RouteLink`.

A typical implementation of RouteAsync looks something like this.

```
public async Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
{
    // Request path is the entire path (without the query string)
    // starting with a forward slash.
    // Example: /Home/About
    var requestPath = context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value;

    if (!requestPath == <some comparison (slice the string up if you need to)>)
    {
        // Condition didn't match, returning here will
        // tell the framework this route doesn't match and
        // it will automatically call the next route.

        // This is similar to returning "false" from a route constraint.
        return;
    }

    // Invoke MVC controller/action.
    // We use a copy of the route data so we can revert back
    // to the original.
    var oldRouteData = context.RouteData;
    var newRouteData = new RouteData(oldRouteData);
    newRouteData.Routers.Add(_target);

    // TODO: Set this in the constructor or based on a data structure.
    newRouteData.Values["controller"] = "Custom"; 
    newRouteData.Values["action"] = "Details";

    // Set any other route values here (such as "id")

    try
    {
        context.RouteData = newRouteData;

        // Here we are calling the nested route asynchronously.
        // The nested route should generally be an instance of
        // MvcRouteHandler.

        // Calling it is similar to returning "true" from a
        // route constraint.            
        await _target.RouteAsync(context);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Restore the original values to prevent polluting the route data.
        if (!context.IsHandled)
        {
            context.RouteData = oldRouteData;
        }
    }
}
```

See the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582232/imlementing-a-custom-irouter-in-asp-net-5-vnext-mvc-6) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565768/change-route-collection-of-mvc6-after-startup#32586837) for some other examples.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use AsyncActionFilter for this purpose.

Suppose your route template: `{controller}/{action}/{myName}`

Implement AsyncActionFilter:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Filters;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Framework.Internal;

namespace ActionFilterWebApp.Filters
{
    public class ThirdPartyServiceActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            var routeKey = "myName";
            var routeDataValues = context.RouteData.Values;
            var allowActionInvoke = false;

            if (routeDataValues.ContainsKey(routeKey))
            {
                var routeValue = routeDataValues[routeKey];
                //allowActionInvoke = ThirdPartyService.Check(routeValue);
            }

            if (!allowActionInvoke)
            {
                //if you setting up Result property - action doesn't invoke
                context.Result = new BadRequestResult();
            }

            return base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
        }
    }
}
```

Add `ThirdPartyServiceActionFilter` on your controller:

```
   [ThirdPartyServiceActionFilter]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```