# Dynamically add route value parameter from database in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, multi-tenant, entity-framework-core

I'm creating multi-tenancy application, with single database per library, for example.

I want to dynamically add library name to route, for example, when user trying to get all books `/Books/GetAllBooks`, I must add library name, which could be retrieved from database, for example: `/LibraryName/Books/GetAllBooks`, so the user can get all books only from the library, which he belongs to.

What should I do? Implement my own IRouter, my own template route, something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Easy path**:

Add `id` to your url. Look at url of this question:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36718499/dynamically-add-route-value-parameter-from-database-in-asp-net-core`

You can change last path segment to anything:
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36718499/foo-bar` still bring you here.

**Without id**:

Implement `IRouter`. You will need to implement two methods:

1) `async Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context)` which parse incoming request and add correct "controller", "action" and "id" values into `context.RouteData` collection. Later, MVC will use this info to call your controller.

2) `VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(VirtualPathContext context)` which builds url (string) for controller+action+id values, provided in `context.Values` collection.

This can help you:

- [Imlementing a Custom IRouter in ASP.NET 5 (vNext) MVC 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582232)
- [Change route collection of MVC6 after startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565768)

Comment: Adding `id` is not the easiest way, because you need to pass it in every your request, which is crazy.

Comment: And, could I use dependency injection in my custom router? For example add `ApplicationDbContext` to `MyRouter` constructor.

Comment: AFAIK, `IRouter`s are created on application start. Create and keep single instance on DbContext in not a good idea.... Both `RouteContext` and `VirtualPathContext` have `Context` property, which is familiar `HttpContext`, which have two `IServiceProvider`-s - `ApplicationServices` and `RequestServices` - better to ask them for instance of your DbContext. Even more better - create some caching service that will keep small amount of routing data in memory and re-read it by timer or by request.

Comment: Ok, seems fine that I could get access to every service in application.