# Custom routes for few Controllers in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Using ASP.NET Core and I need to resolve controller and action from URL depends on the settings in Dictionary (or DB).
URL => Controller, Action

*/something/and/more/2016-10-16* must be processed by controller "Content" and Action "Details"

*/something/special* must be processed by controller "Blog" and Action "Index"

*/super-offer.html* must be processed by "Content"/"Offers"

URLs and related Controller with Action stored in Dictionary, for example.

I need a help with building this handler. Thanks!

Comment: show what you have done so far. If you are not familiar with routing, start from documentation https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/routing.html?highlight=routing

Comment: Resolved question by implementation like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36724177/nothing-happened-with-custom-irouter-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 0):

Solution is an implementation of `IRouter` and replace `RouteContext context` in `RouteAsync` method.