# Getting 404 on IRouter implementation ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to implement my own dynamic router, my plan is to pull routes from my database and create a set of dynamic landing pages, my issue is that I'm getting 404 after setting up context.RouteData to my new route data.

I just want to redirect to my LandingPageController and the Index IActionResult everytime I found a route.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Myproject.Web.Main.Config
{
    public class LandingPageRouter : IRouter
    {
        public VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(VirtualPathContext context)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
        {

            var requestPath = context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestPath) && requestPath[0] == '/')
            {
                requestPath = requestPath.Substring(1);
            }

            var pagefound = GetPages().Any(x => x == requestPath);
            if (pagefound)
            {
                //TODO: Handle querystrings
                var routeData = new RouteData();
                routeData.Values["controller"] = "LandingPage";
                routeData.Values["action"] = "Index";
                context.RouteData = routeData;
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        private IEnumerable<string> GetPages()
        {
            //TODO: pull from database
            return new List<string> { "page-url-title", "another-dynamic-url" };
        }
    }
}
```

I looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582232/imlementing-a-custom-irouter-in-asp-net-5-vnext-mvc-6) but it seems outdated some properties in the context doesn't even exist anymore in RC2.

What Am I missing?

Comment: Please, stop using the term MVC6. You will only spread confusion, when/if a new version of legacy MVC gets released! The former "ASP.NET 5 MVC6" is now named "ASP.NET Core MVC 1.0" to **make it clear** that it's not the next version of ASP.NET MVC5, but **a complete new framework written from scratch**. Also the correct tag is `asp.net-core-mvc`!

Comment: Looks like an interesting scenario...could you please give more info on it? So if a request like `/articles/cavaliers-win-nba-title` comes in you want to map to `/articles/10` url and which gets handled by the `articles` controllers and takes in the article id `10` and also when links are generated you want the mapping to happen the other way...am i right?

Comment: @KiranChalla I'd like to configure routes at the root level like mydomain.com/name-of-the-article and internally and map those routes to my Landing Page controller, it could be either landingpage/Id or landingpage/name-of-the-article

Comment: @Tseng yeah I knew that's a totally new version and it's renamed to Core MVC, I just use that name because old questions are written in that way, so my bad, I'll try to remember it in my next question, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [answer](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4904) and @sock approach, I passed the route builder which is going to pass at the same time the router context

```
public LandingPageRouter(IRouteBuilder routeBuilder)
{
    _routeBuilder = routeBuilder;
}

public Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
{
    var requestPath = context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestPath) && requestPath[0] == '/')
    {
        requestPath = requestPath.Substring(1);
    }

    var pagefound = GetPages().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == requestPath);
    if (pagefound!=null)
    {
        //TODO: Handle querystrings
        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values["controller"] = "LandingPage";
        routeData.Values["action"] = "Index";
        routeData.Values["id"] = pagefound.Id;

        context.RouteData = routeData;
        return _routeBuilder.DefaultHandler.RouteAsync(context);
    }
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Routes configuration in startup.cs

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.Routes.Add(new LandingPageRouter(routes));
}
```

Comment: Glad that works, it looks like the answer you linked to also passed in the `DefaultHandler` directly rather than the `IRouteBuilder` as in your answer - I wonder what the implications are for differences between them. Maybe just a question of Tell don't Ask and preference?

Comment: it was my own post replicated on Github, basically, I implemented the IRouterBuiler since "routes" (as the expression in the app.UseMvc)  implements IRoutebuilder, it feels more "natural" to me to pass it as a parameter, but that's just my opinion due to the lack of documentation is hard to tell the difference between both implementations

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem like the nicest solution but from my testing it should work for your requirements.

---

I injected the default MVC `IRouter` into your `LandingPageRouter`. Then, once you have updated the route data, just call the default router and pass in the context:

```
public class LandingPageRouter : IRouter
{
    private readonly IRouter _router;

    public LandingPageRouter(IRouter router)
    {
        _router = router;
    }

    public VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(VirtualPathContext context)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
    {

        var requestPath = context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestPath) && requestPath[0] == '/')
        {
            requestPath = requestPath.Substring(1);
        }

        var pagefound = GetPages().Any(x => x == requestPath);
        if (pagefound)
        {
            //TODO: Handle querystrings
            var routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values["controller"] = "LandingPage";
            routeData.Values["action"] = "Index";
            context.RouteData = routeData;
            return _router.RouteAsync(context);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> GetPages()
    {
        //TODO: pull from database
        return new List<string> { "page-url-title", "another-dynamic-url" };
    }
}
```

Then just insert the default route wherever you are adding your route in `Startup.Configure`:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.Routes.Add(new LandingPageRouter(routes.DefaultHandler));
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: thanks, I ended up with a similar approach of what you have proposed and definitely your answer help me out to point to the right path!