# Generic controllers. How can I mimic what was possible with IHttpControllerSelector in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, asp.net-core

In a current WebApi project I have a generic controller:

```
public class EntityController<T>
    where T : Entity { }
```

It's created at runtime with a specified type if the controller name in the route matches a type name.

For example: `/api/user/` initialises controller `EntityController<User>`.

To accomplish this, I'm using a custom ControllerSelector:

```
internal class ControllerSelector : DefaultHttpControllerSelector
{
    ... other members omitted for clarity

    public override HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        string controllerName = base.GetControllerName(request);
        HttpControllerDescriptor descriptor;

        Type controllerType = typeof(EntityController<>).MakeGenericType(_entityTypes[controllerName]);
        descriptor = new HttpControllerDescriptor(_configuration, controllerName, controllerType);
        _descriptorCache.TryAdd(controllerName, descriptor);
        return descriptor;
    }

    ... other members omitted for clarity
}
```

It appears this method is not going to work in .Net Core.

I've found and tried these examples but they don't appear to solve my problem:

- This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097141/how-do-i-dynamically-choose-a-controller-in-mvc-core) simply changes the route values.
- This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36680933/discovering-generic-controllers-in-asp-net-core) prints out the controller names have already been loaded (but the title suggests it's what I need).
- Another question suggested creating instances of all the possible generic controllers so they could be picked up by the dependency registration engine but this doesn't feel right.
- Other questions started pointing to towards a custom IRouter but the implementations seemed far too convoluted for what was easily achieved in the previous version.

So, using .Net Core, how can I control the creation of controllers to create a generic controller on the fly?

Comment: Did you ever find a way of doing this?

Comment: @AndrewDavis sadly no, I didn't. It was a PoC porting exercise which I abandoned. Looking back at the options available to me, the most achievable was to create all the possible controller types and register them with a DI container. If you find a way, please add an answer!

Comment: I have gone through the stack trace, replacing the the parts I can via the IoC container.  It appears that the issue in the `ObjectMethodExecutor` which can't be swapped out.