# When and how are route tables created and entries in the route table made?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am learning MVC and 2 questions I often have and not found are:

- I know route table is a class that maintains routing for MVC but how?
- When is the route table actually created? We just register it at application startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route table is populated ("created") at application startup. Although this collection technically can be modified after startup with MVC 5 and prior, [this approach goes against the grain of dependency injection best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565768/change-route-collection-of-mvc6-after-startup#32586837).

Although the route table is static at runtime, the routes that populate the table can be made dynamic through route constraints or by subclassing `RouteBase` in MVC 5 and below or implementing `IRouter` in MVC Core.