# MVC URL Routes with 2 or 3 levels

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I think I have made my routes more advanced than they need to be.
I have a few products that are in a few different 3-level categories, but most of my products are in 2-level categories. No products are in a 1-level category.

So its like this:
* cat/subCat/subSubCat/products
* cat/subCat/products

And I'd like to have my URLs like defined in my routes.
2 Index:   `../Shop/Sortiment/cat/subCat`
2 Details: `../Shop/Sortiment/cat/subCat/product/1/name`
3 Index:   `../Shop/Sortiment/cat/subCat/subSubCat`
3 Details: `../Shop/Sortiment/cat/subCat/subSubCat/product/2/name`

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CategoryIndex",
    url: "Shop/Sortiment/{category}/{subCategory}/{subSubCategory}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Sortiment", action = "Index", subCategory= UrlParameter.Optional, subSubCategory = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProductDetails",
    url: "Shop/Sortiment/{category}/{subCategory}/{subSubCategory}/product/{id}/{productName}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Sortiment", action = "Details", subSubCategory = UrlParameter.Optional, productName = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

My products class have a `Category Category` property. Each `Category` Have a `virtual Category ParentCategory` property that is either null (first level category) or populated with it's parent category.

With 2-level products I can write links like this (with no `subSubCategory` in my routes):

```
@Url.RouteUrl("ProductDetails", new
{
    category = item.Category.ParentCategory.Name,
    subCategory = item.Category.Name,
    id = item.ID,
    productName = item.Name
})
```

But now If I have products that are either 2 or 3-levels I want to write this below, but ofcourse I get nullrefexception on the 2-level products since they don't have 2 `ParentCategory`.

```
@Url.RouteUrl("ProductDetails", new
{
    category = item.Category.ParentCategory.ParentCategory.Name,
    subCategory = item.Category.ParentCategory.Name,
    subSubCategory = item.Category.Name,
    id = item.ID,
    productName = item.Name
})
```

So what do I need to do to get my URLs the way I want to? Maybe it's best for me to redo my routes? Hopefully I gave you enough information.

Comment: I never liked that form of routing. Take a look at attribute routing if you're using MVC 5 (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx). Much easier!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the wrong rout name for the 2-level url. Change to:

```
@Url.RouteUrl("CategoryIndex", new
{
category = item.Category.ParentCategory.Name,
subCategory = item.Category.Name,
id = item.ID,
productName = item.Name
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Rob,

This is the first thing that you should do for your nested routing.

For such nested url, I think you should configures your routes as below:-

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ProductDetails",
            url: "shop/{*subCategory }",
            defaults: new { controller = "Sortiment", action = "Details", subCategory = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just inherit `RouteBase`, which will give you full control over your URLs. One option is just to make them database-driven based on a primary key as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31934144/multiple-levels-in-mvc-custom-routing/31958586#31958586) so you only need to keep track of the primary key to URL mapping in order to pull up your product/category information.

Then, when you specify a URL, you just need to include its primary key as the `id` route value, controller, and action - that is all.

```
@Html.Action("Details", "CustomPage", new { id = 1234 })
```

Note that you could have a single route for product and a single route for category.

Answer (score 0):

```
 routes.MapRoute(
           name: "SubCategoryAction",
           url: "{action}/{id}/{pid}",
           defaults: new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "ActionName", id = UrlParameter.Optional ,pid= UrlParameter.Optional }
           );

//or use traditional AttributeRouting as

[AttributeRouting.Web.Mvc.Route("{action}/{id}/{pid}")]    
public ActionResult ActionName(string id,string pid){}
```