# Insert current URL into @Html.RouteLink parameter to build a link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-partialview, routelink

I am probably going about this the wrong way as i'm a noob to .NET MVC, but is there a way to insert the current url as a parameter into an @Html.Routelink?

I'm passing a partial view into a page to display a list of subcategories based off of the current category.

Here is my controller logic:

```
   public PartialViewResult SubcategoryMenu(string category)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> subcategories = repository.Products
            .Where(x => x.SubCategory.Category.CategoryName == category)
            .Select(x => x.SubCategory.SubCategoryName)
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(x => x);

        return PartialView(subcategories);
    }
```

Here is my partial view which I'm trying to get the current category url into:

```
@model IEnumerable<string>
@foreach (var link in Model)
    {
        @Html.RouteLink(link, new
            {
                controller = "Product",
                action = "List",
                category = "INSERT CURRENT URL HERE",
                subcategory = link,
                page = 1
             }, new { @class = "btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg" })
     }
```

When the page displays, all products and categories are listed, no problem.  When I click a Category, the URL is `http://localhost/Category2` which is what I want.

Click a category, then all of the associated subcategories display in a separate div based on the linq query in the controller just fine.

However, to properly display the products, the url generated for the subcategory view needs to be `http://localhost/Category/Subcategory` and no matter how I tweek the @Html.RouteLink or even an @Html.Actionlink, all I can get is `http://localhost/Subcategory` If i pass in text into the @Html.Routelink for controller= "something" that will display `http://localhost/something/Subcategory` so I've been trying to get the current URL which matches the required category passed into the subcategory @Html.Routelink with no success.

If there is a way to insert the current URL into the subcategory RouteLink it would solve my woes.  If there is a way to accomplish, or a better way to do so, please help.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RouteLink` and `ActionLink` use the `RouteTable` to build outgoing URLs, so it is the `RouteTable` you need to modify to customize URLs, not the `RouteLink` configuration.

You can do this many ways, but the most flexible way to make URLs that are driven off of database data is to [subclass `RouteBase`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31934144/multiple-levels-in-mvc-custom-routing/31958586#31958586).