# MVC 5 Routing issue ActionResult root

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I've question about routing in MVC 
i've created a simple website i defined a controller called `HomeController.cs`

defined my `public ActionResult WebPage(int id)`
the id is the Id of the page i'm displaying my route will look something like:

**Current:**

```
http://localhost:5000/Home/WebPage/1
```

**What i want is:**

```
http://localhost:5000/1
```

My current `RouteConfig.cs`

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

I've tried allot with different routes in `RouteConfig.cs` but im stuck can someone point me into the right direction?

I've searched on StackOverflow something similer to this but didn't find.

Comment: Maybe, define your action as `public ActionResult WebPage(int id)` and add a root route: `routes.MapRoute(name: "Root",  url: "{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "WebPage" });`

Comment: You cant (unless you were to create a route constraint so if the route value is an `int` it will use that method) - you need something to uniquely identify your routes.

Comment: Found my answhere here ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860959/asp-net-mvc-5-dynamic-controller-routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer**

in my controller: `[RoutePrefix("")]` and my Method WebPage `[Route("{id?}")]`

```
[RoutePrefix("")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("{id?}")]
    public ActionResult WebPage(string id)
    {
       return View();
    }
}
```

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
 public class RouteConfig
 {
     public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
     {
         routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

          routes.MapRoute(
               name: "WebPage",
               url: "{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "WebPage" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    url: "{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index",id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try route attribute, it may help you

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute(“{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}”);

  **routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();**

 routes.MapRoute(
    name: “Default”,
    url: “{controller}/{action}/{id}”,
    defaults: new { controller = “Home”, action = “Index”, id = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```

Use attribute like this

```
  [Route(“{id:int}”)]
  public ActionResult WebPage(int id) { … }
```

Answer (score 1):

What Felipe proposes will work, if you apply a constraint on the `id` value.

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "WebPage",
            url: "{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "WebPage" },
            constraints: new { id = @"\d+" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: what if the id is a string value?

Comment: The constraint is not satisfied, so the application will try to match the next route map, in this case the `Default`. For example, given the URL `http://hostname/x`, the `Default` map actually matches, so the application will try to execute the `Index` action of the `XController`.