# Multi level URL routing in MVC ?? facing issue in routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I want an URL like `www.aaa.com/{Categoryname}/{ProductType}/{ProductName}`

where `Categoryname`,`ProductType`,`ProductName` can change dynamically.
ProductType and productname will be optional,categoryname is mandatory.
How do I identify those requests? I want to pass `CategoryID`,`ProductTypeID`,`ProductId` Parameters to identify too.

Any ideas on how I could best set this up?

Comment: Add route https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs

Comment: you can go with attribute based routing
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Comment: you can go with attribute based routing. And why cant you use post ? then you can pass all these as  in data part and it will not be visible in the query string .

Comment: how do i pass Id's which i don't want to display in URL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple levels in MVC custom routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31934144/multiple-levels-in-mvc-custom-routing)