# Route Config for dynamic urls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routeconfig

So Im working on an MVC 4 application. My problem is for a certain controller the Url can be `http://domain/category/clothing/1256` or it can be `http://domain/category/clothing/shirts/formal/128`'. As you can see the depth of the url changes but all must route to the category controller.

Since the max dept of the url is not known, I cant User Routeconfig as I dont know when the parameters will come.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Category",
    url: "Category/{ignore}/{id}/{SubCatId}/{SubSubCatId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "Index", CatId = UrlParameter.Optional, SubCatId = UrlParameter.Optional, SubSubCatId = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "CSPL.B2C.Web.Controllers" },
    constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
);
```

The above code will not work as it accounts for only one level. Any ideas on how to achieve this

The Index method of category controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string id, string SubCatId, string SubSubCatId)
{
    return view();
}
```

Comment: You can only have the last parameter marked `UrlParameter.Optional`. And you refer to 3 parameters  `CatId`, `ChildCatId` and `viewtype`) which do not even exist in your route definition

Comment: yup changed it. but still how to get the Id properly

Comment: You need to create separate route definitions (to the same controller) but its not clear what options you want and you have not shown the signature of the method

Comment: I baiscally want to ignore everthing after Category/ till the parameters begin. or Just match the Entire url from db get corresponding Ids either works for me

Comment: Is there some reason that you want the `id` at the end (as opposed to `/category/clothing/128/shirts/formal`?

Comment: Well the thing the original application is in webforms. there Url rewrite module has been used along with a db provider. so baiscally each time a url like 'category/clothing' is matched in the db to corresponding url like 'Category.aspx?Id=1256' and it is routed to that page. I want to keep the urls as close as possible to the original application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154676/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-sujit-warrier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only option is a catch-all param. However, there's two caveats with that:

1. The catch-all param must be the last part of the route
2. The catch-all param will swallow everything, including `/`, so you'll have to manually parse out individual bits you need with a regular expression or something.

Essentially, you'll just change the route to:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Category",
    url: "Category/{*path}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "Index" },
    namespaces: new[] { "CSPL.B2C.Web.Controllers" }
);
```

Then, your action would need to be changed to accept this new param:

```
public ActionResult Index(string path)
{
    // parse path to get the data you need:

    return view();
}
```

Comment: This worked too. but the answer provided here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31934144/multiple-levels-in-mvc-custom-routing worked better