# How can I have multiple levels of paths for files with extensions (like .jpg) in routing in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to set one controller so it can handle all of these urls:

```
/file/filename.jpg
/file/path1/filename.jpg
/file/path1/path2/filename.jpg
```

etc.

The individual values for path1, path2, etc, will be different, and the filename.jpg will be different as well.

I found a couple of other questions that are sort of similar but don't quite work for me.

[Multiple levels in MVC custom routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31934144/multiple-levels-in-mvc-custom-routing)

My current routing for this is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "BlobStorage",
    url: "File/{*filepath}",
    defaults: new { controller = "File", action = "Index", filepath = UrlParameter.Optional },        
    namespaces: new string[] { "WebApp.Controllers" }
);
```

This sort of works, in that if I use the url /file/path1/blarg, the controller will hit.  But if I put an extension on the blarg, it won't.  /file/path1/blarg.jpg just gives me a 404.

I really hate to set up a bunch of index methods in the controller just to handle multiple levels of paths.

Any ideas?

---

Ok so it looks like the routing is correct but it's the file extension that is the problem.

I tried setting it up with a number of methods to test for /path1/filename, /path1/path2/filename, /path1/path2/path3/filename, and I'm getting the same issue as with the routing code.  The problem seems to be that if I include an extension, the routing won't work.  But it works fine if I don't include an extension.

Comment: If these are arbitrary paths then could you not use  the route tag: [Route("file/path1/path2/filename.jpg")] either in your controller or on specific action?

Comment: I would need to add file/path1/filename.jpg and file/path1/path2/filename.jpg, etc, for each level. I'm tryign to avoid that.